# Laravel project links not working on heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I was given a laravel project I need to get up and running. I am new to laravel, but after allot of work, I believe I got everything configured properly and I deployed the project to heroku.

When I do artisan serve on my guest machine in my laravel project and go to the given url everything works fine all the links works. 
But I deploy it to heroku and my index page shows but none of the links work. 
I get:

```
Not Found The requested URL /register was not found on this server.
```

It seems that running php artisan serve kinda activates the links, but how do I make that happen on heroku???

I should note the app is using blade.php files

What am I missing???

[image: directory structure]

This is in the /resources/views
[image]

My _htaccess inside my public folder is as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I tried adding RewriteBase / doesnt help.
I also tried changing htaccess to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Interesting issue, but maybe you should elaborate more?

Comment: "_but none of the links work_" What does that mean exactly? Wrong domain? Clicking a link gives you an error? Also, I think, no need to run `php artisan serve` on Heroku. And, there is this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

Comment: update to show the error, and I went through all of that and believe I did it all correctly. Also I run php artisan serve on my local machine not on heroku

Comment: did you check by running full url like `yourdomain.com/register` ?

Comment: yeah doesnt work.

Comment: doesn't work on full url too? Is your project stored in any directory ? can you show the screenshot of directory structure?

Comment: added it to the post

Comment: It looks fine had you checked `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: nope where is that?

Comment: What's content of your Procfile?

Comment: web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/